# While statement won't stop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I have a while statement that keeps repeating the text without giving the user a chance to input another value for action. What am I doing wrong? It still doesn't ask for input. I need for the code to display the text once, then ask for input. Presumably, if you typed anything but 1 it would repeat the sequence. But as it stands it simply kicks you out of the loop without the chance to correct the action (As of the last edit, see below.)

```
int action = 0;
while (action != 1)
{ 
    cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
    cin >> action;
}
```

One suggestion was:

```
while (action != 1)
{ 
    cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
    cin >> action;
    cin.ignore();
}
```

That still produces text over and over.

```
while (action != 1)
{ 
    cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> action))
        // ...problems in the I/O stream...
        break;
}
```

This one kicks you out without a chance to input a new action.

Comment: Where's `action` defined?

Comment: Typo, it is action = 0;

Comment: Have you tried, getline(cin, action);

Comment: 220 C:\Dev-Cpp\main.cpp no matching function for call to `getline(std::istream&, int&)'

Comment: do i have to include another function.

Comment: Try to `cin.ignore()` at the end of the loop.

Comment: while (action != 1)
    { 
   
 
     cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
     cin >> action;
     cin.ignore();
   
    }

Comment: still produces repeating text

Comment: prolly better to use do..while instead, feels more natural for your what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you type a character that is not white space and can't be part of an integer, then you have an infinite loop.  Each attempt to input to `action` fails on the invalid character without changing the value stored in `action`.

You could write:

```
int action = 0;
while (action != 1)
{
    cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> action))
        // ...problems in the I/O stream...
        break;
}
```

This will handle EOF and alphabetic characters more gracefully than a continuous loop.  You might need to set a flag or return an error condition from the function or do something else other than break out of the loop.  Always check your inputs for success.

You might also consider outputting the value you're getting stored in `action` in the loop, so you can see what is happening:

```
int action = 0;
while (action != 1)
{
    cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
    if (!(cin >> action))
        // ...problems in the I/O stream...
        break;
    cerr << "Action: " << action << endl;
}
```

This might tell you something useful too.

---

Please show a complete little program that illustrates your problem — an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

For example, I'm testing with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int action = 0;
    while (action != 1)
    {
        cout << " No you must look it might be dangerous" << endl;
        if (!(cin >> action))
        {
            // ...problems in the I/O stream...
            break;
        }
        cout << "Action: " << action << endl;
    }
    cout << "After loop" << endl;
    if (!cin)
        cout << "cin is bust" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Action: " << action << endl;
}
```

That's no longer minimal code — the material after the loop is merely telling me what is happening.  But it does help me ensure that my code is doing what I expect.

What does your equivalent code look like, and what are you typing in response to the prompts — and especially, what are you typing before you get to this code fragment (and what other input activity is going on before you get here)?

Comment: I did that. Worked great for getting out of the loop. It still didn't ask for input. I need for the code to display the text once, then ask for input. Presumably, if you typed anything but 1 it would repeat the sequence. But as it stands it simply kicks you out of the loop without the chance to correct the action.

Comment: What do you mean 'did not ask for input'?  When I run it, I see the 'No look' prompt, then I get to type the data.  Is that not what you see happening?  If your input stream is already in the error state, you will get chucked out of the loop.  You may need to code some recovery actions in place of the `// ...problems` comment (and add braces around the body of the `if` statement).  This might include resetting the error state, reading to the end of line, and perhaps other actions.

Comment: I did the cerr action. It returns 0 like it should. The problem remains that it doesn't ask for me to change it.

Comment: You need to show more code, I think, than you have.  The problem appears to be outside your loop.  Please look up how to create an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Also show or describe exactly what you type into the program.